# C# : Asmx Web Service null authentication headers

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

I am trying to add some authentication to my C# AMSX. I have chosen to try the SOAP headers. I manage to successfully pass across the authentication header in the first call, but subsequent calls come through as NULL.

```
public AuthHeader ApiCredentials;

public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string MachineName;
    public string AccessKey;
}
```

I've decorated my web methods with the below

```
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("ApiCredentials")]
```

Then inside my code, I'm doing the validation but ApiCredentials are coming through as null after the first call.

I've tried re-instantiating the class, adding the headers, etc. but can't understand why it's null.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you are passing the header value from client, but at the service you are able to receive it only for the first time?

Comment: Yes, that's correct... when I make subsequent calls it is not receiving the header and it remains NULL. I have tried adding the header again when making subsequent calls but it still remains as NULL

Comment: have you found a solution ? I get the same problem only when consuming from Xamarin Forms :\ !